# WCF Odata Service w3wp Process Memory Creap

Tags: ios, sql-server, wcf, wcf-data-services, odata

I'm a little confused at the memory use of my WCF service. Brief overview, my wcf service is an odata providor that allows my ipad application to talk to our sql server database.

The problem is that when a client (ipad device using objective c odata library) calls for a simple set of data (say get all customers from the database) the memory of the w3wp process goes up by a few mb's, and never really comes back down. Being the fact that all the client wants to do is one off calls (retrieve a data set, update a data set, delete a data set) than once it has finished its call the memory it used to do the action should be relinquished. This is not the case at all? I gather there is some caching happening or maybe the calling instance is not being disposed.

Can anybody steer me in the right direction so the w3wp is lean and blows the memory away after the call has completed.

Thanks in advance

Comment: As with any managed application, the process will not be very aggressive about freeing up memory unless the machine is under memory stress. There's no need. How do you measure the memory consumption?

Answer (score 0):

does you database reside on the same machine as your web server? if your indexes are not properly applied you will end up consuming much resources. if you are using MS SQL Server check the minimum memory setting for the server. once reached the minimum memory limit MS SQL Server will probably not free it up until restarted. you should also take a look at you binding configuration. if you use a state full (session) binding and not closing the session the service instance is gonna stay in memory for 10 mins (default) waiting for new client requests from the same proxy object.

Comment: Hi dotnetPr0, Thanks for your response. Im happy with the SQL Server memory use, this is seperate to the w3wp memory consumption. I havent made any changes with teh state full binding so i might look into this. Thanks